# Как создать бота в вк

Tags: python, парсер

Я запарсил одно сообщество в вк,чтобы получить user_id человека который сделал пост,имея уже user_id как мне создать бота который будит писать сообщение на этот user_id?

Comment: Метод [`messages.send`](https://vk.com/dev/messages.send) Вам в помощь.

Answer (score 0):

Вам вот сюда: https://vk.com/dev/manuals
А вообще, как точно подметил @nomnoms12 , вам требуется библиотека messages и, скорее всего, метод send().
Вот пример кода такого бота, работающего и в ЛС, и в беседах:

```
if event.from_user: #Если написали в ЛС
            vk.messages.send( #Отправляем сообщение
                user_id=event.user_id,
                message='Ваш текст'
    )
        elif event.from_chat: #Если написали в Беседе
            vk.messages.send( #Отправляем собщение
                chat_id=event.chat_id,
                message='Ваш текст'
    )
```

Советую использовать longpool.